# Starting Jenkins as Root vs NonRoot

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Installed Jenkins on Ubuntu machine.
Initially it auto-started
I created a couple of jobs but was having issues as the some of the scripts required root privileges. So I stopped jenkins using

```
sudo service jenkins stop
```

and then started it using

```
sudo nohup java -jar jenkins.war &
```

This started Jenkins but I can't see the jobs I had created while using it as a service earlier.

I tried replicating the job using the exact same name but that gives me an error saying the job already exists which I guess means it's using the same jenkins environment and directory. Couple of questions regarding this...

1) Is this because I'm running as a different user?

2) Any way I can make the jobs appear in both?

Answer (score 0):

Don't run this service as root. Instead, add an user in your sudoers which can only run the commands needed by your scripts and use it in your scripts `sudo -u myuser cmd`. More at [Ubuntu Sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Comment: I added **jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL** to the visudo file and **sudo -u jenkins /path/to/script** in the job but I get an error saying  **Sorry, user jenkins is not allowed to execute '/path/to/script' as jenkins on machine**

Comment: Do not run the script with sudo. Edit the script and add sudo for those commands that must be run as root. Usually the whole script does not need root.